# LUIS chatbot error

Tags: azure, azure-language-understanding

i a, currently looking into creating chatbots with microsoft azure.
I tried this tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-quickstart-intents-only

But when i go to the endpoint as descriped in step 10, no matter what i insert as parameter  at the end of the url, the editor always shows:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

When i click on "Test", it works fine. Does anyone know, what i do wrong?

Comment: Can  you share the exact URL you entered for the endpoint?

Comment: Can you also provide any screenshots of what you're seeing? Is this SyntaxError appearing in the developer's console?

Comment: Hi @Ginso, Is there any update on this? I just tested it, it works fine for me. Can you provide more details as asked above?